# Recover windows uefi after ubuntu install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I had windows 10 and ubuntu 19 installed on two different disks correctly. Both used UEFI. My motherboard bias is set to UEFI only.

I downgraded from ubuntu 19 to ubuntu 18 and after that my grub disappeared and my bios doiesn't detect windows. The windows disk is unchanged.

Both disks use GUID, on my linux disk there is a 650MB UEFI partition I made at install time. Windows disk just has the main data partition and a 17MB partition which ubuntu says is "microsoft reserved".

So now I need to essentially re-install the windows UEFI bootloader on the existing partition. I have tried using boot-repair but I either didn't use that correctly (not unlikely) or it failed. I also tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510013/cant-boot-to-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-in-uefi)  boot when I do `list disk` in diskpart the windows disk doesn't show up, so I don't havea  `C:\Windows` directory (I also don't have one on the USB I made).

Greatly appreciate the help.

`parted -l`:

```
Model: ADATA SX8200PNP (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  649MB  648MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 2      649MB   501GB  500GB   ext4
 3      501GB   512GB  11.5GB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: ADATA SX8200PNP (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 1024GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  17.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      17.8MB  1024GB  1024GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
```

`efibootmgr -v`:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,edffe2fa-4fdb-4968-a528-fb0d44e90d56,0x800,0x135000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler SE9PMAP, Partition 1   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(6,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x5b49557b,0x2000,0x1d461c0)..BO
```

Boot0001 is a USB... it wasn't plugged at the time I ran the command.

I created the microsoft directory as part of the linked guide.

```
linux-rig:~$ ls /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot
linux-rig:~$ ls /boot/efi/EFI/Boot
bkpbootx64.efi  bootx64.efi  fbx64.efi  grubx64.efi
```

Edit: I tried copying the EFI files from my windows bootable usb in /EFI/Boot into the system EFI partition under Microsoft/Boot didn't work.  Then ran boot-repair with output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Pqy7qzTpyV/

Comment: Need to see your partiitions. Run `sudo parted -l` and post output into question, also for  `efibootmgr -v`.

Comment: Done @PaulBenson

Comment: So your BIOS/UEFI isn't detecting your Windows disk, nvme0n1. Open terminal, run `ls /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot`. Do you see files `BCD`, `bootmgfw.efi ` and `bootmgr.efi`? Also run `ls /boot/efi/EFI/Boot`. Are files `bootx64.efi` and `grubx64.efi` present?

Comment: @PaulBenson  updated my question, i created the microsoft directory previously. Otherwise those two files are present. Note that when I boot up it automatically goes to ubuntu, I don't see grub.

Comment: Looks like the Microsoft bootloaders are gone, but maybe /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi is the backup of one.  Try rename the bootx64.efi to bootx64.efi.sav and then rename bkpbootx64.efi to bootx64.efi, and try to boot the device. Maybe copy the missing Microsoft bootloaders off another macine's EFI, then use efibootmgr to add a Windows boot entry.

Comment: Your Microsoft directory is useless as it's empty. It doesn't have any of the Windows booting files I listed which you need. You cannot repair this from Ubuntu as only MS supply those files on a W10 installation. You have 2 choices. You either re-install Win10 or you can attempt to [repair it](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-uk/sln300987/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-on-a-gpt-hdd-for-windows-7-8-8-1-and-10-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en). You'll need a W10 installation disk or thumb drive to do that. Either way it's a Win10 issue now

Comment: It sounds like you Windows boot files are gone, but any install of Ubuntu would not erase them. You had to delete ESP or erase drive. Just to see details: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I think the drive was erased by me at install time by mistake. I tried to do `bootrec/ Fixboot` but get access denied, and when I do `bootrec /rebuildbcd` it says it can't find my windows installation.

Comment: @oldfred pasted the boot-repair output.

Comment: You do not have typical Windows boot files in ESP, nor an entry in UEFI which normally is not erased. Was Windows install in BIOS/MBR mode and drive converted to UEFI/gpt? Windows only boots in BIOS mode from MBR and only UEFI from gpt. Windows is hibernated, but you can mount read-only. But not sure about Windows fixes. You may want to try on a Windows forum.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the hibernating issue [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107978/cant-access-windows-drive-windows-is-hibernated-refused-to-mount) .

Ended up re-installing after multiple tries using boot-repair.